# Does tomcat webdav support carddav?

Tags: tomcat, webdav, vcf-vcard, carddav

Can tomcat's webdav servlet be used as a carddav address book?  If not does anyone know of a carddav servlet which is free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, tomcat's servlet does not support carddav. Carddav has some pretty specific features not found in a filesystem implementation like what tomcat uses.

If you want a complete carddav server implementation you could look at bedework. But not sure how active it is as there doesnt seem to have been any releases since 2012.

Note that the Carddav protocol is in a constant state of flux as Apple, Google and other industry players adjust their client and server implementations. So protocol support needs to be constantly upgraded. This is very different to plain old servlets where the protocol only occasionally changes.

If you want to add your own backend your [best carddav server library is milton.io](http://milton.io) (I'm the author). Its not free, but i can offer quite reasonable terms for startups, OEM's and smaller enterprises. Milton is very active, is continually updated to work with iOS and other clients, and to match protocol capabilities of other servers like iCloud and Google Contacts (milton was integrated into google contacts for their carddav implementation), and i provide good responsive support.

/Brad

Comment: Does Milton support CalDAV protocol?